# Current time as default value for "TIME" in Mysql

Tags: mysql, time

I am trying to set a column on Phpmyadmin to just "TIME". How can I set the default value to the current time? Only time, no date included.

CURRENT_TIMESTAMP does not work, I also have tried now() but no success. I have looked on the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html) but haven't found anything specific about it.

Comment: What do you mean with "haven't found anything specific about it"? Do you have MySQL 8.0.13 as your link states?

Comment: What I mean is, I found things about DATETIME which will be "CURRENT_TIME" set as default but did not find about just "TIME" such as examples of put default values.

Comment: Looks like you have to use trigger to fill in the default as result of function on insert.

Answer (score 2):

Excerpts from the [documentation link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html) in the question:

> ### Handling of Explicit Defaults as of MySQL 8.0.13
>
> The default value specified in a DEFAULT clause can be a literal
>   constant or an expression. With one exception, enclose expression
>   default values within parentheses to distinguish them from literal
>   constant default values.
>
> […]
>
> ### Handling of Explicit Defaults Prior to MySQL 8.0.13
>
> With one exception, the default value specified in a DEFAULT clause
>   must be a literal constant; it cannot be a function or an expression.
>   This means, for example, that you cannot set the default for a date
>   column to be the value of a function such as NOW() or CURRENT_DATE.
>   The exception is that, for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME columns, you can
>   specify CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default.

So, when supported, use parenthesis:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    what_time TIME NOT NULL DEFAULT (CURTIME())
);
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eefacee3a482b97d0bf59a1c0e03a5c9)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to set a default value for a TIME or DATE column. Switch to a TIMESTAMP column and use `date(t_stamp)` to just get the date. Or `time(t_stamp)` to just get the time.

Comment: Can you set this in the DB?

Answer (score 0):

```
create table test1234235 (foo int, ts timestamp default now());
insert into test1234235 (foo) values(1);
select * from test1234235;
```

Comment: OP asked for type `time`, not `timestamp`